# Ejecutar archivo JS al iniciar Ubuntu

Tags: nodejs, vps

antes que nada advierto que estoy empezando con NodeJS...

Estuve probando lo básico y lo que encontraba en algunos tutoriales, hasta que quise probar la libreria DiscordJS para poder crear un bot, por lo que después en mi computadora hago

```
node discord_test.js
```

Y sin problemas mi bot ya funciona y realiza lo básico que necesito pero, una vez subido toooodos los archivos correspondientes, como tengo que hacer para que al iniciar el vps (por hacer un reboot) o al hacer que ejecute por primera vez no tenga que hacer manualmente "node discord_bot.js"? Ya que si hago esto se quedara siempre pendiente de todo y además de esto tengo varios recursos que ir manejando por consola en el VPS...

Como no sabía como buscar esto en Google (ni en español ni ingles ni con palabras especificas) terminé preguntando por aquí...

Comment: Pues depende de que sistema de inicio use tu distribución. Las últimas suelen venir con `Systemd`, pero tendrías que comprobarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar montando tu aplicación de nodejs como un servicio de Ubuntu y lo configuras para que inicie con el sistema (similar a lo que se hace cuando mandas la aplicación a producción).

Primero debes de darle permisos de ejecutable (sustituye **path** por la ruta de tu archivo):

```
chmod +x ~/path/discord_test.js
```

Luego debes de crear el archivo donde declararas el servicio:

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/discord_test.service
```

Copia y pega la siguiente configuración:

```
[Unit]
Description=Servicio Node.js 

[Service]
PIDFile=/tmp/discord_test.pid
User=<Nombre de usuario>
Group=<Gurpo>
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
WorkingDirectory=/home/<usuario>/discord_test/
ExecStart=/home/<usuario>/discord_test/discord_test.js

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Remplaza los valores de la anterior configuración para que coincidan con las rutas de tu computadora (**WorkingDirectory, ExecStart**), así como los valores de usuario y grupo.

Después debes de habilitar el servicio que has creado:

```
sudo systemctl enable discord_test.service
```

Listo ahora tienes tu aplicación dentro de un servicio que se reiniciara cada que ocurra un error

También puedes monitorear tu servicio mediante un archivo log

```
sudo journalctl -u discord_test.service
```

Ahora dispones de los siguientes comandos para manipular tu servicio (**iniciar, parar y reiniciar**):

```
sudo systemctl start discord_test.service
sudo systemctl stop discord_test.service
sudo systemctl restart discord_test.service
```

Espero te funcione, Suerte!